# Detect chrome new session with extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension that records a time to local storage when a new browser session starts. I created a persistent background page to accomplish this:

```
/*background.js*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    session_start_time = new Date().getTime()/1000;
    var storage = chrome.storage.local;
    storage.set({'beginning':session_start_time});
});
```

I thought that the background page would restart once the chrome session is closed and started again. Or when the extension is reloaded. However, that doesn't happen and the variable `beginning` stays the same that it was the first time I declared it three days ago.

Is there any way to detect when a new session has started and store that time to local storage?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the [`onStartup`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onStartup). As per the documentation:

> Fired when a profile that has this extension installed first starts up.

`chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function callback)`